# Как обучить нейронную сеть распознованию элементов на изображении с помощью OpenCV?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, opencv, нейронные-сети

Передо мной стоит задача обучить неровную сеть распознаванию элементов на изображении.

Как использовать готовые модели с помощью `OpenCV` я нашел. Но мне нужно создать свою модель с распознаванием разных датчиков и шкал.

Готовые модели мне не подойдут.

Как мне обучить модель с помощью `OpenCV`?

Поделитесь пожалуйста ресурсами с примерами или видео.

Comment: А какие готовые модели и как вы грузите? Если это модели на `Tensorflow` - ну так берите `TF` и делайте нейросеть с нужными параметрами. Хотя наверное проще взять `Keras` - он тоже на основе `TF`, но более высокоуровневый и им проще пользоваться.

Comment: @CrazyElf я просто нашел в одном из примеров модель, которую запускают в ImageAI, это от OpenCV. Вот и хочу узнать можно ли свою модель обучить на OpenCV

Comment: И всё-равно непонятно, почему вы думаете, что модель как-то относится к OpenCV? Я посмотрел ImageAI использует torch - вот на torch можете свои нейросетки писать. Я думаю OpenCV может грузить готовые модели, но делать она их не может, внутри там всё-равно torch либо tensorflow для работы с моделями.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел вот такой ролик на ютубе, впринципе нормальный ролик, думаю вам подойдет
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7IZBmjbpqU

Comment: Да, я видел это видео, но тут нет самого процесса обучения. Мне нужно жирнел процесс обучения а не готовая модель.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже не могу разобраться столько ошибок выходит, у меня мак м1, поэтому кажется так сложно,попробуй сделать как тут говорят: https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/custom/index.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).